# Bluetooth chat sample looks messy on ICS

Tags: android, bluetooth, chat, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am new to android programming. I have already coded an GUI für my app and want to complete it with bluetooth functionality. I used the bluetooth chat example from 2.1 and it really looks messy in ICS, seems as if the resolution isn't set properly so that all elements are scaled up. I tried to change the XMLs but I cannot solve the problem.

Has anyone an idea?

THX in advance
Peter

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because of 1 line in the AndroidManifest.xml, change it from

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6"/>
```

.. to something like ..

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

See my reply on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082819/bluetooth-connection-on-android-ics-not-possible).

See this: [issue reported on Android bugtracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34161)